# Force unwrapping (UITextField().text!) Not Crash .But (UILabel().text!) Crash

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextfield, uilabel

Check this please i need explain why  `texField.text!` not crash and   `label.text!`  crash

And as we know  `UITextField` has property `open var text:String?`   and `UILabel` have  `open var text:String?`

```
 let texField = UITextField() 
 texField.text = nil   

 print(texField.text!) // not crash 

 let label = UILabel() 
 label.text = nil 

print(label.text!) //crash
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation of [**`UITextField`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text)

> **Declaration**
>
> `var text: String? { get set }`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This string is `@""` by default.

---

From the documentation of [**`UILabel`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620538-text)

> **Declaration**
>
> `var text: String? { get set }`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This property is `nil` by default.

Please note the subtle difference

Comment: Thanks @vadian. yes i get it so UITextField text is an optional with empty value "" when forced unwrap you will get "" but UILabel text is optional with no value when force unwrap it will crash

Comment: It seems that the `UITextField` behavior is caused by some Objective-C compatibility. But although it's optional it won't be `nil`

Comment: What does the @ mean in @""?

Comment: @Jim This is Objective-C semantics. A literal string has to be marked with a `@` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, you should never force-unwrap optional values like this.
You should use `if-let` or `guard` or any way provided by swift to handle optionals safely.

If a label has no text, then `label.text` will return nil.
However, if a text field has no text then `textField` will return `""` (an empty string). That's why it will not crash if you force-unwrap the `text` property of a text field.

I'm not sure why it designed like this by Apple, but as I wrote above you should handle optionals safely.

Comment: Yes @abullah i know that but i write by this way to ask about what is difference , any way thank you